# DataTables warning: table id=tbl_new- Ajax error after adding serverSide: true,

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var table = $('#canidateregtable').DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    $('#canidateregtable').DataTable( {      
      serverSide: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url"     : "getdata",
            "dataSrc" : "",
        },
  });
```

This is my datatable and some column like

```
"columns": [
            {"data": "user_id",}
           ]
```

Why this error can anyone help me and this is in live in server

Comment: Add searchable: false to your object

Answer (score 0):

Setting attribute of Datatable differs from version of datatable js you are using. 
If you are using Datatable version of greater than `1.10.0` use below syntax.

```js
$('#canidateregtable').DataTable({  
                   "sAjaxSource": "/GetData",  // Your url
                   "bServerSide": true,  
                   "bSearchable": true,  
                   "order": [[1, 'asc']],  
                   "columns": [  
     // You can mention here all your columns you want to display
                       {  
                           "data": "Name",  
                       }
                   ]  
               });  
       }
```

Comment: If my answer solves your problem , Accept and upvote the answer